# Transfer Bootcamp over from a separate hard drive to a partition of a hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, ssd, partition

I have a Macbook Pro with dual hard drives (1tb HD, and a 250gb SSD that I replaced the disk drive with). I have been using the regular HD for my mac and the SSD for my bootcamp. Recently, I found [this article](http://macintoshhowto.com/hardware/how-to-speed-up-your-mac-with-a-ssd-drive.html) explaining how to use the SSD to boost the speed for my mac, as well as my bootcamp. So I want to move everything from the SSD over to a new partition on the HD.

I have successfully made a bootcamp partition on the HD and the computer reads the partition in the Boot Camp Assistant and Disk Utility, but I am unable to boot up that partition. I simply cannot locate it when going though System Preferences or pressing the option key on startup. The old partition (the one on the SSD and that I want to transfer everything from) is found, but the one I just created on the HD is not found anywhere. I have no idea what the problem could be and I would appreciate any help possible.

MORE INFO:

- When I first created the partition (and I tried that twice), the computer rebooted and tried to boot into the new Windows partition, but it got stuck on the blinking cursor and required a force reboot.
- The partition is found on the sidebar of Windows Explorer as well as E: and I can transfer files to E: using Windows Explorer.
- I used to have the single HD with a partition for Windows on it that worked just fine before I got the SSD. I had no problems transferring everything over to the SSD and it has not shown any problems at all.
- The SSD is a Samsung 840 Evo 250gb and the HD is the built-in 1tb 5400-rpm drive that is offered with the Macbook Pro (13").

Comment: out of left field... are you running Paragon NTFS or similar? That will stop the Win partition from being seen as a boot option. Disable from the Control Panel & reboot to see it again.

Comment: Nope! I don't have that installed.

Answer (score 1):

If I read correctly you merely created a partition using bootcamp assistant, which essentially doesn't do anything but create an FAT formatted partition.
OS X will only show you bootable partitions (meaning partitions it finds a system on). You will first need to copy over your data, either including the system or reinstalling and moving over only certain data you want on the SSD.
If you want to do it 1:1 there's also tools like [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/winclone/)